# Rsync / Linux : prevent new directory being created inside destination directory

Tags: linux, terminal, rsync, linux-mint

Pardon my novice-ness, please.

A question regarding the usage of Rsync.
If I specify, as an example, this command:

```
 rsync -av Downloads Downloads2
```

the result is that the directory "Downloads2" is created with "Downloads" as a subdirectory, and, within /Downloads2/Downloads are all of the contents of the original /Downloads directory.

I am wondering if there is an option which will cause rsync to copy the contents of /Downloads to /Downloads2 without creating the /Downloads2/Downloads structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from "man rsync", adding a trailing slash on the source directory will prevent that directory being created:

```
          rsync -avz foo:src/bar/ /data/tmp

   A trailing slash on the source changes this behavior to avoid  creating
   an  additional  directory level at the destination.  You can think of a
   trailing / on a source as meaning "copy the contents of this directory"
   as  opposed  to  "copy  the  directory  by name", but in both cases the
   attributes of the containing directory are transferred to the  contain‐
   ing  directory on the destination.  In other words, each of the follow‐
   ing commands copies the files in the same way, including their  setting
   of the attributes of /dest/foo:

          rsync -av /src/foo /dest
          rsync -av /src/foo/ /dest/foo
```